# Grails 3.1.1 JUnit tests fail with unintelligible error

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Grails domain unit tests don't run, even though application itself runs fine.   Here's the test that Grails inserted automatically.  I didn't make any changes to it, but it doesn't run, failing with an incomprehensible error.

```
package com.grapevine.negotiator2

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification
/**
  * See the API for {@link  grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestFor(ProfileQuote)
class ProfileQuoteSpec extends Specification {

   def setup() {
   }

   def cleanup() {
   }

   void "test something"() {
    expect:"fix me"
        true == false
    }
}
```

Here's the error

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java" -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.3\bin" -Didea.junit.sm_runner -classpath C:\Users\jkramer\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath1.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 com.grapevine.negotiator2.ProfileQuoteSpec
in application

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.<init>(Lorg/grails/datastore/mapping/core/Datastore;Lorg/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager;Z)V

at        grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.mockDomains(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:84)
at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.mockDomain(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:107)
at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.mockDomain(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:106)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:153)
at org.spockframework.runtime.model.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:84)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:88)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.AbstractRuleInterceptor$1.evaluate(AbstractRuleInterceptor.java:37)
at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntimeJunitAdapter$1$2.evaluate(TestRuntimeJunitAdapter.groovy:46)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.TestRuleInterceptor.intercept(TestRuleInterceptor.java:38)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:88)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.AbstractRuleInterceptor$1.evaluate(AbstractRuleInterceptor.java:37)
at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntimeJunitAdapter$3$4.evaluate(TestRuntimeJunitAdapter.groovy:73)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.ClassRuleInterceptor.intercept(ClassRuleInterceptor.java:38)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Process finished with exit code -1

Here is build.gradle:

```
   buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:3.1.2"  //$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.8.2"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.10"

    }
}

version "0.1"
group "com.grapevine.negotiator2"

apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"


ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = 2.2
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false

}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.10.Final"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.10.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:3.0.0.M2"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC6'
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.8.2"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-core:5.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-support:5.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:5.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:5.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:5.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core:5.0.4.RELEASE'
    //  https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/grails-datastore-core/5.0.4.RELEASE
    //  grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

Here is the domain class:

```
    package com.grapevine.negotiator2

class ProfileQuote {

    int scale
    String quote

    String toString() {
        "$quote"
    }
    static constraints = {
        scale range: -5..5

    }
    static getQuote(double scale) {
        int scaleint = (int) Math.round(scale)
        def quotes = findAllByScale(scaleint)
        def numQuotes = quotes.size()
        def r = new Random()
        def i = r.nextInt(numQuotes-1)
        return quotes.get(i)

    }

}
```

Comment: This should work, but you shouldn't test domain classes with unit tests. Instead use an integration test with a real database, and only use domain class mocking when unit testing other classes like controllers or services.

Comment: You will need to provide more detail.  The test at https://github.com/jeffbrown/grapevinedemo/blob/c34422879db32a153670fda391535752cedcf9fe/src/test/groovy/com/grapevine/negotiator2/ProfileQuoteSpec.groovy passes.  One possibility is that you have upgraded an app and have incompatible dependencies in the project.  Another is that there may be something unusual and relevant in your `ProfileQuote` class.

Comment: Burt, point taken.  Seems like the folks at IntelliJ Idea decided otherwise, as these tests are created automatically when you add a domain class in IntelliJ Ultimate.  All these tests are created in the directory src/main/groovy.  Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Scott adding ProfileQuote class and build.gradle to see if that yields any clues.  I sort of doubt its the domain class as the same behavior is observed in every test class created by IDEA when the domain class is created.

Comment: If it is happening with every domain class then I expect something is wrong in the environment or in the project configuration.  This is all very commonly used and generally works, as demonstrated in the app that I provided a link to.

Comment: All my setup was done pretty much automatically by IDEA, including createing and adding these test files to the src/test/groovy folder.  Any clues as to what in the setup could cause tests to fail but app to run normally would be appreciated.  Included my build.gradle.

Comment: @Burt: I use unit tests for domain classes to make sure that required constraints are implemented by the domain class code. Unit tests have to pass in CICD befire Integration tests are run. Integration tests with real DBs then ensure that the code and migrations are compatible with Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, and H2. Am I missing something or overdoing in the two-tiered approach?